# Center align buttons (CSS 3)

Tags: html, css, button, center-align

I'm looking to center align two buttons using CSS 3. So far, I have this code. Right now, the buttons are left-aligning by default. Any help would be great.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="menubutton"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li class="menubutton"><a href="staffing.html">Staff</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menubutton{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: beige;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the `<ul>` like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="menubutton"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li class="menubutton"><a href="staffing.html">Staff</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
ul{
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I love this answer! If you want to remove additional white space you can add "margin: auto" to the ul css.

Comment: I apologize. I already had the <ul> tags, just forgot to include them.

Answer (score 1):

Put your buttons inside a div and use text-align:

```
<div id="container">
    <li class="menubutton"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="menubutton"><a href="staffing.html">Staff</a></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align:center;
}
.menubutton{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: beige;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
}
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xqccde39/)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to put the text-align:center; on the outside of the elements you want to center. If you can't, use a combination of width and margin: X auto;